# I am facing issue while switching between functions in TIC TAC TOE Game VSplayer() and VScomp()

Tags: javascript, function, logic, addeventlistener

I am making Tic Tac Toe Game , I am giving two options for the player to play the game that is VS player and VS computer
Both functions logic is ready but when I am integrating both the code so the function that I run first , only that logic is only implemented
ex if I run first VSplayer then after clicking on VScomp then also VSplayer code is running, and vice versa
I know this code can be optimized but I was facing problems that's why I tried to break both in different functions and try it

```js
// Computer Logic
function VScomp() {
    var Boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
    var info = document.getElementById('info')
    let reset = document.getElementById('reset')
    var a = "X"
    let gameover = false
    info.innerText = `Player X Turn`

    Boxes.forEach(box => {
        box.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (box.innerHTML == "" && !gameover) {

                box.innerHTML = a
                checkWins()
                compchoice()

                if (gameover) {
                    Boxes.forEach((box) => {
                        box.style.cursor = "not-allowed"
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
    // Check Wins
    const checkWins = () => {
        let wins = [
            [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
        ]
        wins.forEach(i => {
            if (Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML == Boxes[i[1]].innerHTML && Boxes[i[1]].innerHTML == Boxes[i[2]].innerHTML && Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML != "") {
                info.innerText = `${Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML} Won`
                gameover = true
                i.forEach(y => {
                    Boxes[y].classList.add("winner")
                })

            }
        })
    }
    reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
        Boxes.forEach(box => {
            box.innerHTML = ""
            gameover = false
            a = "X"
            info.innerText = `Player X Turn`
            Boxes.forEach((box) => {
                box.classList.remove("winner")
                box.style.cursor = "pointer"
            })
        })
    })

    function compchoice() {
        if (!gameover) {
            let flag = false;

            while (!flag) {
                let nums = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
                let box = Boxes[nums];

                if (box.innerHTML === "") {
                    box.innerHTML = "O";
                    flag = true;
                    checkWins();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// // VS player Logic
function VSplayer() {
    let Boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
    let info = document.getElementById('info')
    let reset = document.getElementById('reset')
    var a = "O"
    let gameover = false
    info.innerText = `X Turn`

    Boxes.forEach(box => {
        box.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (box.innerHTML == "" && !gameover) {
                if (a === "O") {
                    info.innerText = `${a} Turn`
                    a = "X"
                }
                else if (a === "X") {
                    info.innerText = `${a} Turn`
                    a = "O"
                }
                box.innerHTML = a
                checkWins()

                if (gameover) {
                    Boxes.forEach((box) => {
                        box.style.cursor = "not-allowed"
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })

    // Check Wins
    const checkWins = () => {
        let wins = [
            [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
        ]
        wins.forEach(i => {
            if (Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML == Boxes[i[1]].innerHTML && Boxes[i[1]].innerHTML == Boxes[i[2]].innerHTML && Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML != "") {
                info.innerText = `${Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML} Won`
                gameover = true

                i.forEach(y => {
                    Boxes[y].classList.add("winner")
                })
            }
        })
    }
    reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
        Boxes.forEach(box => {
            box.innerHTML = ""
            gameover = false
            a = "O"
            info.innerText = `X Turn`
            Boxes.forEach((box) => {
                box.classList.remove("winner")
                box.style.cursor = "pointer"
            })
        })
    })
}
VScomp()
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.game {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 15vh);
}
.customfont
{
  font-size: 56px;
  color: black;
}
.carousel
{
  top:-16px;
}
.carousel-inner
{
  top: 4px;
}
.carousel-control
{
  top: -16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 730px) {
  .game {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 16vw);
  }
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #d0d8d9;
}

.maindiv {
  background-color: #2e2922;
}

.subdiv {
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 22px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
#reset:hover
{
    color: red !important;
}
#reset:focus
{
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

#tic {
  animation: tic 2s linear 1;
}
@keyframes tic {
  from {
    margin-left: -60vw;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
#tac {
  animation: tac 2s linear 1;
}
@keyframes tac {
  0% {
    margin-top: -60vh;
    
  }
  85% {

    margin-top: 0;
    
  }
}
#toe {
  animation: toe 2s linear 1;
}
@keyframes toe {
  from {
    margin-right: -60vw;
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 0vw;
  }
}
.winner
{
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite ;
  
}

@keyframes blink
{
from {
color: transparent;
}
to {
color: black;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>

<body>
    </div>

    <div class="maindiv min-vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column align-content-center flex-wrap">
        <div class="text-white d-flex justify-content-center">

            <div>
                <h1 class="ps-3" id="tic">TIC</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="ps-3" id="tac">TAC</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="ps-3 text-end" id="toe">TOE</h1>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="subdiv d-flex h-100 p-4 flex-column">
            <div class="gameInfo">

                  <div>
                                            <button class="VScomp" onclick="VSplayer()">VS Player</button>
                    <button class="VSplayer" onclick="VScomp()">VS Comp</button>
                  </div>
                <h2>
                    <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center" id="info"></div>
                </h2>

            </div>
            <div class="game mt-4 d-grid  justify-content-center ">
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-top-0 border-start-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-top-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-top-0 border-end-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-start-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-end-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-start-0 border-bottom-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-bottom-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-bottom-0 border-end-0 "></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg"
                    id="reset">Reset</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="JQUERY-Version.js"></script>
    <script src="temp.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well and explain in more detail what the problem is.

Comment: When page loads i already had called VScomp function so firstly user get to play vs computer but when user clicks on VSplayer also then also VScomp code logic plays and if i initalize the function to VSplayer then user get to play against user but now when user clicks on VScomp then also VSplayer code ligic implemenets

Comment: I have edited your question, converting your code into a snippet. I would like to help you solving the issue, but it seems something is still missing, there is no tic-tac-toe table appearing when I run it. Can you make adjustments so the problem you are asking about will reproduce in the example?

Comment: Sure I will also provide the complete CSS of it ,I am sorry for not providing it before as I am using grid system

Answer (score 0):

`VScomp` and `VSplayer` both add event handlers to your boxes.  If you call both functions, both sets of event handlers will be added so both handlers will be called when a box is clicked.

To fix this, either remove the event handlers before adding the new ones, or use a single event handler that looks at the current playing mode to decide what to do.

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: Use your debugger to set a breakpoint within the 2 box click handlers.  When VScomp and VSplayer are both called, and you click a box, see that the debugger stops at both breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call both `VScomp` and `VSplayer` to support both use-cases, but, besides of that, you will need to switch off the events when the other use-case is chosen. This is a working example that you can start your thought-process from:

```js
var isComp = true;
// Computer Logic
function VScomp() {
    var Boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
    var info = document.getElementById('info')
    let reset = document.getElementById('reset')
    var a = "X"
    let gameover = false
    info.innerText = `Player X Turn`

    Boxes.forEach(box => {
        box.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (!isComp) return;
            if (box.innerHTML == "" && !gameover) {

                box.innerHTML = a
                checkWins()
                compchoice()

                if (gameover) {
                    Boxes.forEach((box) => {
                        box.style.cursor = "not-allowed"
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
    // Check Wins
    const checkWins = () => {
        let wins = [
            [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
        ]
        wins.forEach(i => {
            if (Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML == Boxes[i[1]].innerHTML && Boxes[i[1]].innerHTML == Boxes[i[2]].innerHTML && Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML != "") {
                info.innerText = `${Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML} Won`
                gameover = true
                i.forEach(y => {
                    Boxes[y].classList.add("winner")
                })

            }
        })
    }
    reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (!isComp) return;
        Boxes.forEach(box => {
            box.innerHTML = ""
            gameover = false
            a = "X"
            info.innerText = `Player X Turn`
            Boxes.forEach((box) => {
                box.classList.remove("winner")
                box.style.cursor = "pointer"
            })
        })
    })

    function compchoice() {
        if (!isComp) return;
        if (!gameover) {
            let flag = false;

            while (!flag) {
                let nums = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
                let box = Boxes[nums];

                if (box.innerHTML === "") {
                    box.innerHTML = "O";
                    flag = true;
                    checkWins();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// // VS player Logic
function VSplayer() {
    let Boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
    let info = document.getElementById('info')
    let reset = document.getElementById('reset')
    var a = "O"
    let gameover = false
    info.innerText = `X Turn`

    Boxes.forEach(box => {
        box.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (isComp) return;
            if (box.innerHTML == "" && !gameover) {
                if (a === "O") {
                    info.innerText = `${a} Turn`
                    a = "X"
                }
                else if (a === "X") {
                    info.innerText = `${a} Turn`
                    a = "O"
                }
                box.innerHTML = a
                checkWins()

                if (gameover) {
                    Boxes.forEach((box) => {
                        box.style.cursor = "not-allowed"
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })

    // Check Wins
    const checkWins = () => {
        let wins = [
            [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
        ]
        wins.forEach(i => {
            if (Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML == Boxes[i[1]].innerHTML && Boxes[i[1]].innerHTML == Boxes[i[2]].innerHTML && Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML != "") {
                info.innerText = `${Boxes[i[0]].innerHTML} Won`
                gameover = true

                i.forEach(y => {
                    Boxes[y].classList.add("winner")
                })
            }
        })
    }
    reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
        Boxes.forEach(box => {
            box.innerHTML = ""
            gameover = false
            a = "O"
            info.innerText = `X Turn`
            Boxes.forEach((box) => {
                box.classList.remove("winner")
                box.style.cursor = "pointer"
            })
        })
    })
}
VSplayer();
VScomp();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.game {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 15vh);
}
.customfont
{
  font-size: 56px;
  color: black;
}
.carousel
{
  top:-16px;
}
.carousel-inner
{
  top: 4px;
}
.carousel-control
{
  top: -16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 730px) {
  .game {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 16vw);
  }
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #d0d8d9;
}

.maindiv {
  background-color: #2e2922;
}

.subdiv {
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 22px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
#reset:hover
{
    color: red !important;
}
#reset:focus
{
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

#tic {
  animation: tic 2s linear 1;
}
@keyframes tic {
  from {
    margin-left: -60vw;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
#tac {
  animation: tac 2s linear 1;
}
@keyframes tac {
  0% {
    margin-top: -60vh;
    
  }
  85% {

    margin-top: 0;
    
  }
}
#toe {
  animation: toe 2s linear 1;
}
@keyframes toe {
  from {
    margin-right: -60vw;
  }
  to {
    margin-right: 0vw;
  }
}
.winner
{
  animation: blink 1s linear infinite ;
  
}

@keyframes blink
{
from {
color: transparent;
}
to {
color: black;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
</head>

<body>
    </div>

    <div class="maindiv min-vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column align-content-center flex-wrap">
        <div class="text-white d-flex justify-content-center">

            <div>
                <h1 class="ps-3" id="tic">TIC</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="ps-3" id="tac">TAC</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="ps-3 text-end" id="toe">TOE</h1>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="subdiv d-flex h-100 p-4 flex-column">
            <div class="gameInfo">

                  <div>
                                            <button class="VScomp" onclick="isComp = false">VS Player</button>
                    <button class="VSplayer" onclick="isComp = true">VS Comp</button>
                  </div>
                <h2>
                    <div class=" d-flex justify-content-center" id="info"></div>
                </h2>

            </div>
            <div class="game mt-4 d-grid  justify-content-center ">
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-top-0 border-start-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-top-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-top-0 border-end-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-start-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-end-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-start-0 border-bottom-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-bottom-0 "></div>
                <div class="box fw-bolder fs-3 border-bottom-0 border-end-0 "></div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg"
                    id="reset">Reset</button></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="JQUERY-Version.js"></script>
    <script src="temp.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I used an `isComp` flag to know whether the secondary moves are to be made by the comp. If so, then the comp will make the moves. Otherwise a human move will be expected.

A better solution would be to create a single cell event listener for each cell and implement two validators. Depending on what mode you are in, the right move validator would be chosen.

Validator in comp mode: first player is on move and the move to be made is valid.

Validator in human mode: any player is on move and the move to be made is valid.

In comp mode call a comp move function after the player has moved as long as the game did not finish.